# iOS app rejected due to cookies without asking permission

Tags: ios, cookies, permissions, app-store-connect, review

My app was recently rejected for App Store release with the following reason:

> We noticed your app accesses web content you own where you collect cookies. Cookies may be used to track users, but you do not use App Tracking Transparency to request the user's permission before collecting data used to track.

The last part is correct: I do not apply App Tracking Transparency.

The first part is surprising:

- I do not explicitly access cookies by HTTPCookieStorage
- I show a terms-of-use webpage which is included in the app. It does not access any cookies. It has links to external sites that do, but I only navigate to these by switching to safari (using UIApplication.shared.open(...))

So: How do I figure out how/when cookies are accessed by my app, which makes apple require App Tracking Transparency?

Comment: In the web page you include into your app do you use some JavaScript from others third party ? You can on simulator and go to your app cache directory to see which cookies are created.

Comment: Nope - the webpage does no JS. Good call about the cache directory for simulator, that will come in handy next time I need to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up asking Apple about the haps, and the reply stated the following:

> we still find that your app indicates the collection of cookies on launch

After a bit back-and-forth, I removed some text in the bundled terms-of-use webpage - something copy-pasted from the website supporting the app, that indeed *indicated* collection of cookies... Completely irrelevant for the app.

That did the trick, and the app is approved.

Comment: Good for you that you correct find this strange issue